# CodeIgniter how to sort joined record

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have following query in CodeIgniter:

```
$user = $this->db
    ->select('users.*, login_logs.ip_address, login_logs.date, login_logs.userid')
    ->from('db.users')
    ->join('db.login_logs', 'users.userid = login_logs.userid')
    ->group_by('users.userid')
    ->get()
    ->result_array();
```

It works very good but I have to select last record for each user( in login_logs table) but now I'm getting first record.
I have tried :

```
->order_by('login_logs.idlogin_logs', 'DESC')
```

but it didn't work.

I have no idea how to do it. 
Is there any easy way to reach it?

**@edit**

I have triend ASC/DESC. No changes.

Present query:

```
 SELECT `users`.*, `login_logs`.`ip_address`, `login_logs`.`date`, `login_logs`.`userid`
FROM `db`.`users`
JOIN `db`.`login_logs` ON `users`.`userid` = `login_logs`.`userid`
GROUP BY `users`.`userid`
```

Comment: Have you try `ASC` instead of `DESC`?

Comment: ah I know use `MAX(login_logs.idlogin_logs)` or `MIN(login_logs.idlogin_logs)` in the select since u have group by

Comment: @Abhik Chakraborty, it doesn't work.

Comment: can u get the query which is generated and post it ?

Comment: hmm i think its `select_max();` and `select_min();` where u need to specify the field name. `$this->db->select_max(login_logs.idlogin_logs)`

Comment: How to do it with single query?

Comment: u can just specify in the same query. just add that line along with the rest of the code u have `->select_max(login_logs.idlogin_logs)`. I guess the active record set does the rest for u. check here http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: It doesn't work. I will write own query, without active record. Thanks for help :)